# Does anyone know when Cordova for Android will be updated & built against okhttp v2.x?

Tags: android, cordova, okhttp

I have other libraries in my app that use okhttp 2.x, and I can't build against them both as I get runtime exceptions. Sadly okhttp didn't leave the deprecated methods in their SDK when they moved to v2.x :-(

Given okhttp 2.x was released in may 2014, I'm hoping Cordova are due to release a new version built against the new libraries soon, as the longer they leave it, the more issues everyone is going to face!

Comment: Have you considered contributing a pull request to Cordova to fix the problem? That's how open source works: you have the opportunity to fix what you don't like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been removed in the latest version of cordova-android. See the [blog post](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html). If you need okhttp, you can install it as a cordova plugin [here](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-okhttp).